# Kali won't load after installation

Tags: boot, kali-linux, acpi

I need help to install Kali on a new Asus Rog Strix laptop (AMD Ryzen 7 6800h, NVIDIA 3060). After installing it on a ssd (400 Gb) separate from Windows 11, after rebooting and selecting the OS Kali in the bootloader (grub), an error appears and then nothing happens.

The image (`kali-linux-2022-W23-installer-amd64.iso`) was taken from the repository (bare metal). Before that, I tried to load the Kali Live desktop, but the download from the USB flash drive did not go beyond this error. I also tried to install Ubuntu (I did not find a separate installer for AMD in it), but the same story. However, if you download Ubuntu Live, then the desktop loads and goes beyond this error, which I will attach below in the photo.

Tails also works in boot mode from a USB flash drive. By the word works (Ubuntu and Tails), I primarily mean booting the system beyond a black screen with errors. I specifically turned off ssd with Windows in order to exclude the influence of the second OS on booting, and put Kali on one single disk, but the same story :(.

It writes UEFI errors, but it isn't clear if these errors are why the booting does not continue or if there is another issue. I don’t know if this is important, everything works on a virtual machine, though not without brakes. Please advise.

[image: screenshot showing boot errors]

Answer (score -3):

`nomodeset` helped me through the issue.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer, but please explain a bit more. Remember that the point of answers is helping future users. I am guessing you mean the grub2 `nomodeset` option, so please explain that and explain where and how you added it.